# Anybody experiencing ANR when using MediaPlayer as service?

Tags: android

Hi I'm getting ANR (Application Not Responding) errors but I can't understand why. If I click "Wait" everything works perfectly and the ANR doesn't come back anymore.

Now, I do know that when using MediaPlayer as a service is good practice using .prepareAsync and the onPrepared() method rather than simple .prepare() and .start(). It doesn't lock the UI thread and works great.

The problem is that all my ANRs are not happening when opening files (you would guess higher processor there), but randomly when they are playing and when the cpu is at few % at most. As I mentioned earlier NOTHING is remotely close to being unresponsive and there is little left on the UI thread.

The only clue is that I don't get ANRs the first time I play a track, but only after it has been changed. I thought that the prepareAsync threads were colliding and I added a lock myself. no change.

I tried to release the media player each time before starting a new track. no change

I tried to reset, stop etc in many sequences. no change.

Has anybody experienced the same thing?

As a workaround, is there any way to automatically dismiss the ANR? I know it's not the answer but I can't find any options. I am on a rooted tablet (I compiled the ROM) and it is only for myself - no distribution

thanks

Comment: Fixed. turns out it was a bug on how the service was started. nothing to do with prepareAsync() or the media player in general.

Comment: I'm having the same problems as you - what was the problem for you? I'm also using a Service and I get ANRs especially when loading (only using prepareAsync - even tried prepare in an AsyncTask).

Answer (score 2):

A standard Service actually runs on the main Thread, if you are seeing ANRs perhaps you should move the entire MediaPlayer to another Thread. To quote the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService)

> Most confusion about the Service class actually revolves around what it is not:
>
> - A Service is **not** a separate process.
> - A Service is **not** a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

You are already using `prepareAsync()`, but as you stated the error occurs while the MediaPlayer is running, not preparing.  Without more detail on what exactly causes the ANR, I believe switching to a HandlerThread is your best option.

Comment: thanks, I meant that the prepareAsync() would not be locking the UI.In any case I think I found that the issue is not actually related to the Media Player but to the way I communicate to the background service that includes the MediaPlayer. I'm still on it but I hope I can fix it because it's rather annoying! Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: I took some liberties quoting you to focus on the idea that you should move the whole MediaPlayer to a separate HandlerThread. This way your users will never see an ANR, so you don't have to worry about automatically dismissing it (which I don't believe you can do.) I'm sorry if you feel I misquoted you, I'll remove it, I want to expand my answer anyway.

Comment: no problem, thanks! In any case I started a new question at the lonk below. I think there lies the problem somehow.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663767/how-to-pass-data-from-activity-to-service-without-starting-a-new-instance/15664138?noredirect=1#15664138