# How to pass data from Activity to Service without starting a new instance?

Tags: android

I have no problem in passing data to a service using intent, extras, etc and using startService(intent)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, MediaPlayerService.class);
intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.PLAY_PAUSE);

intent.putExtra("URI", URI);
intent.putExtra("TITLE", content.toString());
//PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
startService(intent);
```

The problem is that the service is a background service using MediaPlayer to play music. Using startService each time I'm afraid that it might be spawning multiple players, and eventually I get an ANR (even if everything is working smoothly)

All I need is to tell the MusicPlayerService to play a new track. Any ideas? As you can see from the code I also tried PendingIntent (suggested on the net) but it didn't seem to work

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I checked and if I did

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.d(TAG,"super called "+startId);
...
```

I saw startId was constantly increasing and giving timeouts eventually. Solved by calling

```
stopService(intent)
...
startService(intent)
```

so simple and yet so many headaches to find it out!

Answer (score 2):

> Using startService each time I'm afraid that it might be spawning multiple players

No. There will be precisely zero or one instance of your service. If the service is already started, `startService()` does not start a second instance, but merely calls `onStartCommand()` of the existing instance.

> and eventually I get an ANR

The stack trace should point out the source of your difficulty.

Comment: mmm, strange. Nice to see that it won't spawn multiple players. As for the ANR, the stack trace is unfortunately not very helpful..

Comment: Actually it looks like it started a new service each time indeed!I did do super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);Log.d(TAG,"super called "+startId); and the startId was constantly increasing. Solved by calling stopService(intent) before starting another one

Comment: @EmanueleRonchi: `startId` is not a process ID. If you read the documentation for `Service`: "A unique integer representing this specific request to start." You can think of this as being a command ID for the commands sent to `onStartCommand()`. `startId` will be different for each incoming command, regardless of whether the service had to be created or not.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. However, something was off and was fixed by stopping the service before starting it. It really looked like it was starting a new service rather than resuming it. I'll keep looking, maybe it was thread-related somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 1):

Bind to your service and sent your message through Messenger.

Comment: thanks I'll try that as well, looks like a better way to communicate with it